# Trim &nbsp; and <br> tags from String java or javascript

Tags: java, javascript, regex, trim

I want to remove starting and trailing br and nbsp tags from a string using java or javascript.

Input and desired output  are hosted in jsfiddle.net because Stackoverflow is not letting me to post html content.

http://jsfiddle.net/HwDf9/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?

```
request.replace(/^\&nbsp\;|<br?\>*/gi, "").replace(/\&nbsp\;|<br?\>$/gi, "").trim();
```