# How to trim <br>, spaces and &nbsp from start and end of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to combine trimming of `<br>` or `<br />`, whitespaces and `&nbsp;`'s from the start and end of a string.

There are a few similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360447/trim-nbsp-and-br-tags-from-string-java-or-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603527/how-to-remove-trailing-white-spaces-and-nbsp-from-the-start-and-end-of-a-str)), but I couldn't get all 3 working in PHP.

Currently I have this; `#(^(&nbsp;|\s)+|(&nbsp;|\s)+$)#` needing combining with this: `/(^)?(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+$/` but have no idea how to accomplish it. I'm using a PHP preg_replace.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: can you reproduce it in [here](http://phpfiddle.org/)?

Comment: @DrixsonOseña It is just a preg_replace: `$text = preg_replace("my-busted-regex", " ", $text);`. I've tried a bunch of variations, so not sure what you'd want to see in phpFiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?php

$test_cases = array(
    "<br>&nbsp; spaces and br at the beginning&nbsp;",
    "<br /> spaces and br with / at the beginning &nbsp;",
    "<br> <br /> more examples &nbsp;",
    "&nbsp; even more tests <br />",
    "<br/> moaaaar <br> &nbsp;",
    "&nbsp;<br> it will not remove the <br> inside the text <br />&nbsp;"
);

$array = preg_replace('#^(<br\s*/?>|\s|&nbsp;)*(.+?)(<br\s*/?>|\s|&nbsp;)*$#i', '$2', $test_cases);

foreach($array as $item) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($item) . "<br>";
}

?>
```

Test cases are pretty much self explanatory.

edit:

I was having issues with the previous function when using large complex strings. Also I just wanted the end of the string trimmed this worked for me

`preg_replace('#(<br\s*/?>)$#i', '', $string);`

Comment: I don't think this is working - try `var_dump(htmlspecialchars($item));` instead in the foreach loop - nothing is being removed.

Comment: Thanks - still looking for `&nbsp;`'s to be removed as well. This string for example: `"<br/> moaaaar <br>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>"`

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a function using a series of `str_replace()`, which is (to my understanding) twice as fast as `preg_replace()`, and you can easily extend the function to add more matches. just a thought...

```
$string = "My&nbsp;string<br />needs<br>a trim\n";

function trim_string($string) {
    $string = str_replace("<br>",'',$string);
    $string = str_replace("<br />",'',$string);
    $string = str_replace("&nbsp;",'',$string);
    $string = str_replace(" ",'',$string);
    return $string;
}
echo trim_string($string);
```

outputs `Mystringneedsatrim`

Comment: Thanks, but this affects the whole string, not just the start/end.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I should have used `trim()`. Regardless, I see you got your answer :)